# Is there any way to convert the .li layout inspector file to a .png image?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I'm trying to get a screenshot image file of the whole layout, and it looks like when I export the layout file in the layout inspector, Android Studio is able to upload that back in and reconstruct the image.

Is there any way to get the image itself from layout inspector?

Comment: I'd use a desktop screen capture tool. There does not seem to be a built-in "export the image" option, if that is what you are seeking.

Comment: And what is the purpose of this? Just take a screenshot; `Alt` + `Print` copies it into the clipboard.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler Getting the full length screenshot. The .li file seems to have all the information necessary to get a scrolling screenshot without actually scrolling and creating the image.

Comment: @ml888 don't think that there is any way to convert `.li` to `.png` or alike... but you could create an AVD, which has an extremely tall screen (to compensate for the scrolling) and then take an on-device screenshot.